# Show image while in home screen

Tags: android, image, service, background

So, I'm actually developing an app that will show an image-full screen image- after couple of seconds even when you are in your home screen.
I searched about it and all I've got was running in background services.

thankyou for help.

Comment: Working on the UI thread from a background service is not advised in such a way. By the way, what are you trying to achieve? Your question seems incomplete

Comment: I'm going to set a count down timer then after that an image will show.
I successfully  did that but I when i.m in my home screen or other app it doesn't appear. what I'm trying to do is the image will appear even on the other app,I searched about it and it was draw over other apps

Comment: in this case why don't you just open an activity of your app with the full screen image? (and hidden toolbar)?